# Fast Enumeration through UICollectionView Cells - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, fast-enumeration

I am trying to fast enumerate through all of my collection view cells, however this implementation below is giving me a warning.

```
for cell in self.collectionView?.visibleCells() as [UICollectionViewCell] {

    // Do Stuff
}
```

Error below appears on first line:

> Operand of postfix '?' should have optional type; type is
>   '(UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
>   UICollectionViewCell'

I've tried messing around with optionals and had this working in Xcode 6 Beta 6, but to no avail in "Beta 7"

How do i get rid of this error? /  Write a loop that goes through all my CollectionView Cells ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `collectionView` property is now an *optional* `UICollectionView?`, so you have
to unwrap it:

```
for cell in self.collectionView!.visibleCells() as [UICollectionViewCell] { ... }
```