# Make a UILabel push other UILabels when it expands?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uilabel

So I'm making an app, and its going to have a couple of uilabels, stacked on top of each other, all collapsed to a certain size. I have a button that expands each uilabel, individually, but I want to make it so that when one expands, the positions of the others move. Is there a way to do it other than changing the y position of each label, every time?

my code atm is

```
    @IBAction func expandbutton(sender: AnyObject) {

    uilabel1.frame = CGRectMake(uilabel1.frame.origin.x, uilabel1.frame.origin.y, uilabel1.frame.width, uilabel1.frame.height + 120)

    uilabel2.center = CGPointMake(deltaX, deltaY)
    uilabel3.center = CGPointMake(deltaX, deltaY)
    ....

}
```

Comment: You can do it in `For` loop

Comment: Also you are moving the `uilabel2` twice ,

Comment: @Roma-MT What do you mean in a for loop? And no, I meant to write uilabe3.center... sorry about that!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop

Comment: You can iterate through ur labels in a `for` loop , and move each y position in 1 line of code -> that is pretty much what I meant. you can use fast enumeration for this like it is described in this example
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662520/fast-enumeration-through-uicollectionview-cells-swift